# I cannot uninstall a package by pip (Python)

Tags: python, pip

When I run **"pip list"** on my computer that has MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, some packages are listed on the terminal:

```
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ sudo pip list
altgraph (0.10.2)
bdist-mpkg (0.5.0)
bonjour-py (0.3)
macholib (1.5.1)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
modulegraph (0.10.4)
numpy (1.8.0rc1)
pip (9.0.1)
py2app (0.7.3)
pyobjc-core (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Accounts (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-EventKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Message (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Social (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.5.1)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
python-dateutil (1.5)
pytz (2013.7)
scipy (0.13.0b1)
setuptools (18.5)
six (1.4.1)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
xattr (0.6.4)
zope.interface (4.1.1)
```

However, when I uninstall one (**altgraph**) of these packages, I get an error such as below:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-BQys7K-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph'")]
```

I also checked some paths and versions:

```
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which python && python --version
/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.10
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which pip && pip --version
/usr/local/bin/pip
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which easy_install && easy_install --version
/usr/bin/easy_install
setuptools 18.5 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (Python 2.7)
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which pytz && pytz --version
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which scipy && scipy --version
IST01-12345:~ myMac$ which altgraph && altgraph --version
```

Although "pytz", "scipy" and "altgraph" are shown in the list, I cannot find their paths and versions. What do you think? How can I uninstall them, or how can I remove these packages from this list? Does using python under /usr/bin instead of python /usr/local/bin occur this problem?

Comment: If there is confusing or unaccountable information, please ask me. I am trying to find a way to handle the problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security issue? If so, run pip as superuser:

```
sudo pip uninstall <packagename>
```

One of the problems with Python installs is that there are often multiple, and they differ quite a bit in where they put their files, esp. across the Python 2 and Python 3 divide, and with several major sources of Python builds (Apple default, Homebrew, Python.org builds, ActiveState, Enthought Canopy, ...). Some of these install using Apple location guidelines, some using Unix conventions, some using other Unix conventions, some in the user space, .... Basically, it's a mess, just knowing where the files live. Just a few of the possible places to look:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
```

I have often found that I have to `cd` to these file locations, root around to find the `lib` and `site-packages` directories, and use `rm` (often `sudo rm -rf <file-or-directory>`) to truly remove some vestiges of modules, esp. if a mix of `easy_install`, `pip install`, `python setup.py install` install techniques were used.

The `/Library` and `/System/Library` prefixes suggest you are using / depending on Apple-installed Python, in official locations. So `sudo` authorizations a must. The `cd`/`rm` route possibly required.

Comment: Many of the packages are encased in folders, in which case you'd need `sudo rm -rf pytz` for a recursive delete.